# Find the time (in seconds) Tom would need to catch Jerry

Tags: java

I have a question about The 2015 ACM-ICPC Asia Phuket Regional Programming Contest Problem I.Tom and Jerry.The problem is as follow.            Tom and Jerry are very fond of cat and mice games, which might be rather obvious to you. Today they are playing a very complicated game. The goals are simple as usual though, Jerry would be running and Tom would have to catch Jerry. However, today Jerry is running on a perfect circular path with radius R meters, at a constant speed of V m/s. Initially Tom is sitting at the very center of the circle. He wants to catch Jerry as soon as possible, but we all know, Tom is not very intelligent. Instead of calculating an optimal direction to catch Jerry, he is just running towards Jerry. As Jerry is also moving, the path Tom has taken start to look like a curve.At any given moment, Tom’s position is between Jerry’s current position and the center of the circle. Tom is also moving at a constant speed of V m/s, same speed as Jerry. Find the time (in seconds) Tom would need to catch Jerry.             Input file has T (T <= 10000) test cases, each case consists of two integer R and V.  Here, 0 < R, V <= 10000. For each test case, print the case number and the time Tom will need to catch Jerry. Floating point rounding error lower than 1e-5 will be ignored by the judge.

Example

Sample Input
4 
45 100
5 1547
1000 10000
5668 5467

Sample Output
Case 1: 0.70685835
Case 2: 0.00507691
Case 3: 0.15707963
Case 4: 1.62854830

How can I solve the problem?
I can't post image.In the question,it has an image.You can see the image in the below link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfzU4.jpg

Thank in advance.

Comment: This reminds me of the bee flying back and forth between two bicycles problem.  It's probably something simple like since they're moving at the same speed, it's probably how long it takes Tom to traverse from the center to the edge, since he's instantaneously changing directions, but I'd have to think about it.  If we had to account for "smooth" changes in acceleration and whatnot, this wouldn't work (presumedly the bee can instantaneously about-face; in reality it'd have to either slow down some, first, or overshoot).

Comment: It's a differential pursuit curve.

Comment: If Tom advanced toward the edge at a constant speed (radius-based progress), it'd be easy, but we have to take into account his changing of direction (his speed is determined by change in angle, as well), so that makes it a little trickier.  Here's a [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PursuitCurve.html) to what @stackoverfloweth mentioned I think; it seems to be what you need for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at solving something like this:

[image]